# Bigcommerce stencil bug with related_products front-matter

Tags: bigcommerce

I think there may be a bug with related products. I have added the following front-matter to my `product.html` page:

```
product:
    related_products:
       limit: 20
    similar_by_views:
       limit: 20
```

Regardless of the limit I set for `related_products`, I am never able to get more than 5 back from the server. If I set it to 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, it works, but if I set it to anything larger than 5, I only get 5 products.

This is not true for `similar_by_views`. That settings works correctly. Is this a bug with `related_products`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 related products is the limit of the core app to be displayed. Stencil documentation is being revised to reflect this. It is intended behavior, not a bug.